# Large Amounts of Byte[] Kept in Memory by StreamAsIStream Instances

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory, profiling

I have been memory-profiling a C# .NET WPF application, and I have found that there is a large number of Byte[] instances staying in memory. They are predominantly kept alive by instances of **StreamAsIStream** handles, which reference System.IO.MemoryStream instances, which finally reference the System.Byte[] instances.

[image]

These System.Byte[] instances amount to over 5mb of memory, so I'd like to understand why they're sitting in memory and if there's anything I can do to get rid of them (unless they're necessary, of course).

[image]

I've tried to do some research on my own, but I have been unable to find much. The only thing I've seen pertains to the use of ElementHost when hosting WinForms elements in a WPF application, but ElementHost is not used throughout the program.

I was able to put breakpoints in the constructor of **SystemAsIStream** and found that these objects are instantiated when I create new instances of BitmapImage using streams, but they appear to persist even after the BitmapImage instances have been GC'd.

I have also used WinDBG to try to examine the **SystemAsIStream** instances, but I am not very experienced with using that program. The most I could gather was that the instances are strong handles, but I basically knew that already.

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening and what I can do about it? Even more information about StreamAsIStream would be appreciated.

Further information: I'm using .NET 4.0 and my target platform is x86.

**Edit:** the BitmapImage instances are created with the following code:

```
    public static BitmapImage BitmapImageFrom(Stream stream)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        image.StreamSource = stream;
        image.EndInit();

        return image;
    }
```

The stream is from the following:

```
stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(string.Format(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/{0}/{1}", folder, imageName))).Stream;
```

I've tried creating the BitmapImages by setting their CacheOption field to BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad and disposing of the stream, but that doesn't seem to make a difference (could be wrong -- I may have done it wrong or something).

Comment: Does forced collection of all generations help? If not - please show how exactly you create those BitmapImages.

Comment: No, those byte[] instances never go away during garbage collections. See post's Edit for how the BitmapImage instances are created.

Comment: Looks as if this particular problem is [ancient](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/11359/how-to-find-the-cause-of-streamasistream-leak)

Comment: From looking at the [reference source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/StreamAsIStream.cs), the class seems to be a wrapper that is allowing a standard managed stream to be manipulated by the the COM [IStream interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). This gives me the idea that the reference is probably being held indirectly by native code holding a reference to the IStream interface.

Comment: Are these bitmaps displayed by some control or something? Because maybe instead of copying the bitmap data, the display control is keeping a reference to the IStream that can give access to the data.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that thread on RedGate. Unfortunately it didn't give me any ideas. The Bitmaps are displayed on a control, yes. I'll investigate that, thank you for the idea. That could be the issue.